# Uniform Convergence proof and limit inside integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have:

$$f_n(x) = ie^{ine^{ix}}$$

We are to evaluate:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} ie^{ine^{ix}} dx$$

We must first prove that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniform convergence.

I am not sure what $f(x)$ is equal to. My guess is that:

$$f_1(x) = f(x)$$

**Please confirm the above!**

$f_{1}(x) =  f(x) = ie^{ie^{ix}}$

But

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ie^{ine^{ix}} = \infty$$

The book points that the function **is supposed to be uniformly convergent.** How then?

Answer (score 2):

$$f_n(x) = i\exp\left(in e^{ix}\right) =i\exp(in\cos x)\exp(-n\sin x)$$
hence
$$|f_n(x)| = \exp(-n\sin x)$$
and:
$$\left|\int_{0}^{\pi}f_n(x)\,dx\right|\leq 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-n\sin x}\,dx\leq 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-\frac{2n}{\pi}x}\,dx<2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{2n}{\pi}x}=\frac{\pi}{n}.\tag{1}$$
This is enough to show that the limit is zero. We cannot have uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ since the sequence $\{f_n(0)=ie^{in}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is not converging, and uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.

Also notice that, as stated in my other answer, we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp\left(in e^{ix}\right)\,dx&=&2\int_{n}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\frac{2\cos n}{n}-2\int_{n}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\\&=&\frac{2\cos n-2}{n}+2\int_{n}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
so $I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp\left(in e^{ix}\right)\,dx$ is a real number, and $|n I_n|\leq 2$.